# Obtain the indices of neighboring elements within a radius

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a NxN matrix and I want to find indices (or at least count) of non-zero elements within a radius R for each element in matrix. The matrix will be large so I plan to do the calculations using Numpy, and I need the indices because this matrix is linked to another with data-storage (which is a python list [[]] of objects).

The matrix looks like this:

[image: Matrix]

where Green is the selected cell, Yellow - the surrounding area.

The main problem is the moving stencil, either in loop or vectorized.

I tried the following code which gives the correct coordinates (all within radius and excluding center) relative to the point, but I dont know how to apply it to the numpy array:

```py
r = 2
neighbor_coords = []
for i in list(itertools.product(range(-r, r+1), repeat=2)):
    if any(i) and np.sqrt(i[0]**2 + i[1]**2) <= r:
        neighbor_coords.append(i)

>>> [(-2, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -2), (0, -1), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

Expected output is the indices or count of neighboring elements.

Comment: you are using euclidean distance. This wont work in case you have a radius of 3 or more. You aught to use the city block distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you part way there.  You can use the convolve function in `scipy` to convolve your matrix with a kernel that you generate.  This below will count the non-zero entries within the reach of the kernel.  Note that I transformed the input matrix to ones so that it was summing the non-zero locations, not the values.

```
In [74]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [75]: from scipy.ndimage.filters import *                                    

In [76]: a                                                                      
Out[76]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 5, 5]])

In [77]: a_ones = np.where(a>0, 1, 0)                                           

In [78]: a_ones                                                                 
Out[78]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [79]: k                                                                      
Out[79]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [80]: convolve(a_ones, k, mode='constant')                                   
Out[80]: 
array([[2, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 1]])

In [81]:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def find_ind(array,center,radius):
...     a = np.indices(array.shape).reshape(2,-1).T
...     return a[np.abs(a-np.array(center)).sum(1)<=int(radius)]-np.array(center)
...
>>> find_ind(np.zeros((7,7)),[4,4],2)
array([[-2,  0],
       [-1, -1],
       [-1,  0],
       [-1,  1],
       [ 0, -2],
       [ 0, -1],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 0,  2],
       [ 1, -1],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 2,  0]])
```

Of course you can input the array itself in the function

Answer (score 1):

Try using a combination of `meshgrid` to generate the coordinates, `flatten`, and `reshape`.

In this example, frame_height and frame_width are the number of rows and columns in your array. `x` and `y` are the center of the circle, and `radius` is its radius.

```
    colnums, rownums = np.meshgrid(range(frame_width), range(frame_height))
    dist = np.sqrt(
        (colnums.flatten() - x) ** 2 + 
        (rownums.flatten() - y) ** 2
        )
    keep_mask = (dist < radius).reshape((frame_height, frame_width))
    indices = np.where(keep_mask)
```

Here I've used a true circle (not a diamond), but you can do whatever shape you want by changing the way the distance is calculated. You will also have to add the part about counting non-zero elements (or whatever) but that is easy once you have `indices`.

Basically the issue is that boolean part can only really be done on a 1d array, so you have to use meshgrid, flatten, and reshape. Then you can get your indices back into the 2d array (using `np.where`), or if you want you can use the boolean array `keep_mask`.

Also look into `np.unravel_index` which allows you to convert indices into the flattened array into n-dimensional indices into an array of arbitrary shape.